# Store product URL for each retailer and product with Django models

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a database storing information for various products and retailers. I'm trying to capture information about all URLs that certain products can be found on retailers websites. In essence, think of a traditional price checker website. There is a product page that shows all the URLs of the product stocked by various retailers.

It's probably a rather easy solution but I'm having issues wrapping my head around it.

I'm not sure where should I capture the URL of certain product for each retailer.

I believe URLs should be stored in the Product model which would require some kind of dictionary to hold information about retailer and product URL sold by those retailers.

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    manufacturers = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=manufacturer_list,default='30')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=country_list,default='30')


class Retailers(models.Model):
    retailer_name = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=retailer_list,default='30')
    retailer_website = models.URLField(max_length=250)
    retailer_page = models.URLField(max_length=250)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4,decimal_places=2)
    product_image_url = models.URLField(max_length=250)
    product_manufacturer_url = models.URLField(max_length=250)
    product_size = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=bottle_sizes,default='30')
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reatailers = models.ManyToManyField(Retailers)
```

Hope that makes sense, 
Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra fields to the intermediate model of a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    reatailers = models.ManyToManyField(Retailers, through='ProductRetailer')

class ProductRetailer(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailers)
```

[see documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)